# Binomial Expectation of Convex Function

Tags: pr.probability, fixed-point-theorems, fa.functional-analysis

Suppose $x$ has a binomial distribution with chance $\alpha$ drawn $k$ times, and let $f(x)$ be a positive convex real valued function.  I would like to evaluate

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} \mathbb{E} [f(x)]$$

Ultimately, this is for the following purpose: Suppose $\alpha^*(y)$ is defined by the equation

$$\mathbb{E} [f(x) \mid \alpha] \equiv \alpha + y$$

I am interested in studying the implicit function $\alpha^*(y)$ so defined.  Any tips to characterize it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does the notation $\mathbb{E}[ \cdot \mid \alpha]$ mean? Please tell us more about what this problem is for, but the paper referenced at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21858/expected-values-over-binomial-distributions
by Sah ("The Effects of Child Mortality Changes on Fertility Choice and Parental Welfare", equations 4 - 7) offers a property which sufficed for a similar problem I was tackling. Namely, \begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} \mathbb{E}[f(x)] = k \cdot \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} {k-1 \choose j} \alpha^j (1-\alpha)^{k-1-j} (f(x+1)-f(x)).
\end{align*} (cont.)

Comment: Lots of other nice properties are derived in this paper, and the answers to that question offer some further reading.

Edit: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/122897/is-the-binomial-expectation-of-convex-function-convex-in-p?rq=1 which has much more analysis of this type.

Comment: The notation $\mathbb E[f(x)\mid\alpha]$ is a way of writing the expected value in which its dependence on $\alpha$ is given a place in the notation, so that, for example, one can write expressions like $\mathbb E[f(x)\mid\alpha]/\mathbb E[f(x)\mid\alpha_0]$. Suppose that 20 pages after you first write about the random variable $x$ whose distribution depends on $\alpha$, it becomes appropriate to assign a probability distribution to $\alpha$.  Then the notation refers to the conditional expected value while remaining consistent with the way it was used earlier.

Comment: +1.  I changed \;|\; to \mid.  I think that is standard.

Comment: So $\alpha^*(y)$ is the value of $\alpha$ for which the bias of $f(x)$ as an estimator of $\alpha$ is $y$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://mathoverflow.net/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/comment).